# Delaying a second css property until after the first transition is complete

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a css animation transition for it's height when you hover over it. When you also hover over it, the background color change from pink to orange. However, I don't want this background color to change until *after* my height is done transitioning. Is there a way I can do this? I looked into using `transition-delay` but it seems that it can only be applied to one transition property? Thanks!

```css
div {
  margin: 3rem;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: pink;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

div:hover {
  height: 20rem;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify delays for any property you like:

```css
div {
  transition: height 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}
```

(In this case the last 0.3s defines the delay for the background color, see e.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition))